# How to call function in controller from template only if variable true

Tags: angularjs

I have this row:

```
 <a class="btn btn-default btn-xs" ng-click="list.showReview = list.showReview == $index ? -1 : $index; getValues(object.Id); "><i class=" glyphicon glyphicon-list-alt"></i></a>
```

I want `getValues()` method in controller to be called only  if `list.showReview`
variable `true`.

Any idea how can I implement it?

P.S. can I use if else statement in HTML ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assume `list.showReview` is a boolean variable. Then you can try this

```
 <a class="btn btn-default btn-xs" ng-click="list.showReview && getValues(object.Id)"><i class=" glyphicon glyphicon-list-alt"></i></a>
```

Answer (score 1):

You could make it a button and apply the `ng-disabled` directive. If `list.showReview` is true, then `ng-disabled` will make the button disabled, see below.

```
<button class="btn" ng-disabled="list.showReview" ng-click="getValues(object.Id); "><i class=" glyphicon glyphicon-list-alt"></i></button>
```

In general, I would suggest moving your logic for whether or not getValues() is executed inside your controller.  You'll end up polluting your html templates if you continue to put excess logic inside them.